# How can we get table object which is inside a form using formid - in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form like below

```
 form name="myform" id="myform">
      <table>
          <tr role="row" class="odd selected">
          <td class="ng-scope sorting_1">1</td>
          <td class="ng-scope">.NET</td>
          <td class="ng-scope">Intermediate</td>
          <td class="ng-scope">0</td><td class="ng-scope">true</td>
</tr>
      </table>

    </form>
```

using the form id is there anyway to get the table object inside this form ?
i have tried the below way,that way i can get all the inputs inside the form but i couldn't get the table object

```
$("form#myform:input").each(function(){
 var input = $(this); 
});
```

can anyone suggest a way to do the same.

Comment: what is wrong with $("#myForm table") ?

Comment: @Kenny what you mean by wi ? i didnt get you

Comment: edited my comment, pressed enter by mistakely while writing the comment

Comment: @Kenny ya it is working and it is returing the entire table object is there anyway to see the row element of that table ?

Comment: then you can use $("#myTable table tr") or dirctly $("#myTable tr")

Comment: @Kenny i have tried that but  
my final objective is i want to replace a table's row with this content , so if i am getting an object like this then i cannot able to replace it, can you help me to solve this issue ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130336/discussion-between-kenny-and-arunprasanth-kv).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want

HTML

```
<form id="myform">
 <table>
   <tr role="row" class="odd selected">
      <td class="ng-scope sorting_1">1</td>
      <td class="ng-scope">.NET</td>
      <td class="ng-scope">Intermediate</td>
       <td class="ng-scope">0</td><td class="ng-scope">true</td>
  </tr>

  </table>
 </form>
 <table class="dest-table">
    <tr role="row" class="odd selected">
      <td class="ng-scope sorting_1">1</td>
      <td class="ng-scope">a</td>
      <td class="ng-scope">b</td>
      <td class="ng-scope">c<td class="ng-scope">d</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $("#myform tr").on("click", function(event) {
         $(".dest-table tr").html($(event.currentTarget).html());
   })
```

})

Fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/ja454mfx/1/

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you want to do with the table, but you can access it using the following selector:

```
var yourTable = $("#myform table");
```

The selector is looking for `table` element inside element with ID `myform`.

If you want to get the row selector (as you mentioned in comments), then you can use add selector for `tr`:

```
$("#myform table tr").each(function(){
   var currentRow = $(this); 
   // do what you need with current row
});
```

Comment: my requirement is i want to get the tr inside that table,how can i get it ?

Comment: it is showing entire object rather than the data of that particular tr , is there any way to see the data of that tr, i mean just like a row element ?/

Comment: my final objective is i want to replace a table's row with this content , so if i am getting an object like this then i cannot able to replace it, can you help me to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

What about this :

```
$("form#myform>table").each(function(){
 var table = $(this); 
});
```

You use ">" to access the direct descendant  which is a table.

**EDIT:**

```
$("form#myform>table>tr").each(function(){
 var trInner = $(this).html(); 
});
```

Comment: it is showing entire object rather than the data of that particular tr , is there any way to see the data of that tr, i mean just like a row element ?/

Comment: my final objective is i want to replace a table's row with this content , so if i am getting an object like this then i cannot able to replace it, can you help me to solve this issue ?

Comment: no , the edited answer will give a tr object but i cannot replace another tr with this object. I have some other table in my application and i want to replace one of its row with this tr that is my requirement